# Unable to connect more than one USB 3.0 Basler Cameras

Tags: ros

I am trying to connect 2 Basler Cameras by setting respective device ids using [pylon_camera](http://wiki.ros.org/action/fullsearch/pylon_camera) node. But it does not pick the device id correctly. Without setting the device id it works.

I have set the permission for USB devices as mention here (https://www.baslerweb.com/fp-1510124600/media/downloads/documents/readme/README.txt) by executing ./setup-usb.sh . But when I specify the device id (e.g, 2676:ba02:2:2:8) in the config file it does not detect the corresponding device. This is the error it is throwing

```
[ INFO] [1531469242.730556970]: Trying to open the following camera: 2676:ba02:2:2:8
 [ERROR] [1531469242.994999730]: Couldn't find the camera that matches the given DeviceUserID: 2676:ba02:2:2:8! Either the ID is wrong or the cam is not yet connected
```

Maybe device id was set incorrectly. Anybody who can comment on this much appreciated.

I asked in the ROS community (https://answers.ros.org/question/297261/unable-to-connect-more-than-one-usb-30-basler-cameras/ ). Still no reply

Answer (score 1):

After spending lots of time, finally found the proper way to get this resolved. Here are the steps you need to follow,

Once  [pylon_camera](http://wiki.ros.org/action/fullsearch/pylon_camera) is installed, there is a lib called pylon_camera_write_device_user_id_to_camera which can be found in the 
/ros/lib/pylon_camera/ directory. Just plug one camera at a time and assign a device id to the selected camera as follow,

```
ros/lib/pylon_camera/pylon_camera_write_device_user_id_to_camera traffic_left<this is the id of the camera>
```

Then in the config file, define the device which was assigned.

Comment: In the [current version of pylon_cameras that is provided by Basler](https://github.com/basler/pylon-ros-camera) the command has been renamed.  This worked for me: `rosrun pylon_camera write_device_user_id_to_camera <my_camera_name>` .